# Why would a company treat its web server hardware setup as confidential?

Tags: hosting, datacenter, security

Recently I was reading a blog post ([in Russian](http://habrahabr.ru/company/selectel/blog/136798/)) about a huge datacenter. Commenters asked to show shots of racks with equipment installed by customers.

The authors declined saying that customers treat their hardware setup as confidential and so the policy is not to shoot such racks and not publish photos of them even though equipment is not labeled in any way that would allow to associate it with any specific customer. However they can't explain why customers would want to conceal their equipment.

This doesn't make sense to me. First of all, [some companies](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/stack-overflow-rack-glamour-shots/) have no problem just showing their equipment. Then, even if equipment is shot it can't be associated to a customer - whoever can have an IBM server.

Why would datacenter customers treat their servers so confidential that they can't be taken pictures of? What would happen if someone saw a *blue server with IBM logo* on a photo?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's just a matter of liability.

If one is responsible of a place where client-owned data is stored, some companies will feel compelled (rightly so, don't you think?)  to guard that in a protective manner.

Not that the actual picture actually matter much, though they obviously could be  used to help identify  equipment in datacenter, not that this matters much.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you if it's unnecessary ?

The clients probably think more in the direction of: "What if there was some small thing that could Id them and we missed it ?".

Even so you can't do anything with it, it's just a bit of privacy for the clients.